# What are the established ways which can or cannot harm a Changeling?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion, changeling

Obviously Star Trek changelings are quite robust.

I know the answers to some of these, but I'll just leave it to someone to provide a complete answer.

To harm means to kill or to do damage to a changeling that can be permanent or at least last for some period of time or may require medical intervention to repair.

Various means of attack could include, among others:

- physical attack
- physical separation into pieces
- explosives
- radiation
- extreme heat or cold
- energy weapons
- vacuum
- chemical attack
- biomedical attack
- denial of reversion to gelatinous state
- emotional abuse (jk)
- others

*In canon*, what do we know causes damage to a Changeling, and what doesn't cause damage?

Comment: Downvoters? Explanation?  Please don't give me the ole "this is a list question".  It's not and that's the most misunderstood reason to DV/VTC.

Comment: “Downvoters? Explanation?” 1. Calm down. It’s just two downvotes. Stop demanding explanations. No-one owes you anything. 2. I don’t think the question needs your list of possible means of attack. A means of attack has either been seen in the show or not.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm perfectly calm.   How do you expect the site, questions,  and people's voting behavior to improve if people don't explain their thinking?

Comment: people might have downvoted you for fun, or by accident, or you might have been downvoted by some wayward software bot. Maybe it’s worth asking for explanations, but I don’t remember ever seeing a comment asking for downvote explanations being followed by a downvote explanation.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:  I most definitely **have** seen people give useful explanations that have led to improvements or clarifications.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that Q, a Douwd, Nagilum, Trelane, etc., could easily kill a Changeling.

Answer (score 4):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Changeling) has a list of methods by which they have been injured and the episodes in which these methods are put into practice:

> It has been suggested that Changelings are biologically immortal and therefore never die of old age. (DS9: "[Children of Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_Time_(episode))", "[Behind the Lines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Behind_the_Lines_(episode))") However, it has been proven possible to kill Changelings by a number of means.
>
> Severe cases of radiation poisoning can prove fatal. (DS9: "[The Adversary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Adversary_(episode))") Changelings have also been killed by phaser or disruptor fire, at sufficiently high settings. (DS9: "[Crossover](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Crossover_(episode))", "[Apocalypse Rising](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_(episode))") A Changeling has also been observed succumbing to trauma following the impact of a ship crashing into a planetary surface (a crash in which the ship's intertial dampeners had failed). (DS9: "[The Ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ship_(episode))")

In summary:

- Severe case of radiation poisoning
- Phaser or disruptor fire at a sufficiently high setting
- Trauma following the impact of a ship crashing into a planetary surface

Comment: Dr Bashir used a hypospray to tranquilise Odo. He also became unconscious when struck in the head with a falling rock.

Comment: @Richard: good points. Really, a rock? How do they justify that? He doesn't really have a head.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - It's been asked on the site before. The short answer is that it's not been explained. Chalk it up to a production error.

Comment: This answer doesn't speak to what *cannot* harm a changeling.

Comment: @ThePopMachine everything else?

Comment: @InguShama:  Funny.   But obviously I mean, what are the ways people have tried to harm a changeling or that they might think would harm a changeling, but don't.